# GoLang Reverse Proxy Multiple Target URLs Without Appending Subpaths

Tags: go, proxy, reverse-proxy

I am trying to write a reverse proxy in Golang using `net/httputil/ReverseProxy` that is able to forward requests to different target URLs without appending the proxy URL subpaths.

For example: 
If my proxy URL is PROXYURL, (not enough reputation to post more than 8 links, even fake example ones, so hence replacing link with PROXYURL),

I would like `PROXYURL/app1` to forward requests to `TARGET1/directory` and I would like `PROXYURL/app2` to forward to `TARGET2/directory2`

Currently, I create the following ReverseProxy http handlers using `NewSingleHostReverseProxy()` and bind them to the desired subpaths (`/app1` and `/app2`).

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
)

func main() {
    port := "6666"
    proxy1 = httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy("http://target1.com/directory")
    proxy2 = httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy("http://target2.com/directory2")

    http.Handle("/app1", proxy1)
    http.Handle("/app2", proxy2)
    http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%s", port), nil) 
}
```

However, whenever I run this and send a request to `PROXYURL/app1`, it proxies `TARGET1/directory/app1`. I understand that from the description of ReverseProxy, this is the intended behavior (appending the subpath of the proxy URL to the target). However, I was wondering if it is possible to map a proxy URL subpath (`/app1`) to another target URL without the subpath being appended to the target URL.

In summary, I want

http://proxy.com/app1 -> http://target1.com/directory

and

http://proxy.com/app2 -> http://target2.com/directory2

not (as is currently happening)

http://proxy.com/app1 -> http://target1.com/directory/app1

and

http://proxy.com/app2 -> http://target2.com/directory2/app2

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#StripPrefix Take a look at the example and replace the FileServers with your proxies. You can change the Host header by setting the [Director function](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy) (set Request.Host to `"target1"` or `"target2"`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that by providing a custom Director function instead of using the default one provided by NewSingleHostReverseProxy() (https://golang.org/src/net/http/httputil/reverseproxy.go) , I was able to implement the behavior I wanted. I did this by setting req.URL.Path to target.Path and not appending the original req.URL.Path. Other than that, the director function was very similar to that in reverseproxy.go.

Comment: can you show the code please, where multiple servers were proxied.